# Extract single value from curl in Python

Tags: python, curl, json-rpc

I am using the API found here: https://docs.deribit.com/v2/?shell#public-ticker
(specifically the shell documentation for curl requests)

I am looking to run the request on multiple instrument names. Then I would like to extract a certain value from the response. How would I get the specific value of `"min_price"` from the result produced?

```py
import requests

name = "BTC-29NOV19-8000-C"
r = requests.get("https://testapp.deribit.com/api/v2/public/ticker?instrument_name="+name)

print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example uses requests and not curl so I will assume that is what you want:

You can use `json.loads()` which will convert the response to a `dict` , this allows you to access the `key` needed. In this case result.min_price.

```
import requests
import json

name = "BTC-29NOV19-8000-C"
r = requests.get("https://testapp.deribit.com/api/v2/public/ticker?instrument_name="+name)

result = json.loads(r.text)

print(result)
print(result['result']['min_price'])
```